# Self outer join get nulls also

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database with records like the following structure in the table;

```
 id, message,         date_added, fid,  fid_sort
 19, "start uploads", "2012-02",  NULL, 20
 20, "end uploads",   "2012-03",  19,   20
 21, "start uploads", "2012-04",  NULL, 20
```

I have an entire database set up like this where the `fid` in some cases matches the `id` of another record. I'd like to return all records that have matching start and end dates and just the start date if it doesn't have a corresponding end date `fid` like below:

```
19, "start uploads", "2012-02", "end uploads", "2012-03", 20
21, "start uploads", "2012-04,  "",            NULL,      20
```

`fid_sort` is the number that links to `pid_sort` of a parent table in order to extract the task name.

```
SELECT startdt.id, startdt.message, startdt.date_added, enddt.message
    , enddt.date_added, stardt.fid_sort
FROM tasks as startdt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks as enddt
    ON startdt.id = enddt.fid
    AND enddt.message LIKE '%end%'
WHERE startdt.message LIKE '%start%'
    AND enddt.fid_sort = 20
```

Currently this only returns matching records but I want null end date records also. I want all startdate records regardless of whether they have a correspondent end date record.

Comment: it doesnt though, im getting records only like 19, "start", "2012-02", "end", "2012-03" and not 21, "start,  "2012-04,  "",    NULL

Comment: my query is actually enddt.msg like '%start% and startdt.msg like '%end%' because my message is actually a string containing end or start

Comment: Unless you provide a [MRE] how can we help you? Especially when the example you've provided works!

Comment: check out my sql statement now

Comment: because my message field contains a string suck as task end or task started indicitating what the log entry is referring to

Comment: BTW if your `msg` column always starts with `start` or `end` (as opposed to being in the middle of the string) then for better performance use `LIKE  'start%'` and `LIKE  'end%'`

Comment: So why do you have `AND enddt.fid_sort = 20` ?? Because when there is no end date `enddt.fid_sort` will be null, which is what is causing rows with no end date to be filtered out.

Comment: all records have fid_sort in original table tasks

Comment: All records have `startdt.fid_sort` but only records with a matching end date have `enddt.fid_sort.`

Comment: Did you by chance mean to write `AND startdt.fid_sort = 20`? Seems odd to be filtering on your left joined table.

Comment: yes i did, assuming that is wrong? should be stardt.fid_sort=20 , im getting correct records now. i believe so but on initial look it looks like im getting records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `AND enddt.fid_sort = 20` to `AND startdt.fid_sort = 20` solved my problem e.g.

```
SELECT startdt.id, startdt.message, startdt.date_added enddt.message
    , enddt.date_added, stardt.fid_sort
FROM tasks as startdt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks as enddt ON startdt.id = enddt.fid
    AND enddt.message LIKE '%end%'
WHERE startdt.message LIKE  '%start%'
    AND startdt.fid_sort = 20
```

Comment: To be honest I recommend deleting the question - its not going to help anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT startdt.id, startdt.msg, startdt.date, enddt.msg, enddt.date
FROM yourtable as startdt
LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable as enddt ON startdt.id = enddt.fid
WHERE startdt.msg = 'start'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to what you have changed about the query and how it fixes the problem?